# apache seg fault, do_bind_function in libphp5.so

Tags: php, apache2, gdb, segmentation-fault

I keep getting this log entries on ubuntu 10.04 lts:

```
# vim /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Sun Mar 18 08:58:01 2012] [notice] child pid 4300 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:02 2012] [notice] child pid 4302 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:03 2012] [notice] child pid 4303 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:03 2012] [notice] child pid 4304 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:04 2012] [notice] child pid 4305 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:04 2012] [notice] child pid 4306 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:04 2012] [notice] child pid 4307 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sun Mar 18 08:58:04 2012] [notice] child pid 4308 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I made a coredump of apache and tried to figure out what the problem is, but I don't understand what exactly this means and what I can do to get rid of the seg-faults:

```
# gdb /usr/sbin/apache2 core

[...]

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f78121f36ad in do_bind_function ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f78121f36ad in do_bind_function ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#1  0x00007f781223614c in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00007f7812235ee0 in execute () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007f781220d92d in zend_execute_scripts ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007f78121b92f8 in php_execute_script ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007f781229b08d in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#6  0x00007f781605e320 in ap_run_handler (r=0x7f7816d4b4a8)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/config.c:159
#7  0x00007f7816061c88 in ap_invoke_handler (r=0x7f7816d4b4a8)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/config.c:373
#8  0x00007f781606f878 in ap_process_request (r=0x7f7816d4b4a8)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/modules/http/http_request.c:282
#9  0x00007f781606c728 in ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7f7816d452d8)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/modules/http/http_core.c:190
#10 0x00007f7816065ed8 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x7f7816d452d8)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/connection.c:43
#11 0x00007f7816074847 in child_main (child_num_arg=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:662
#12 0x00007f7816074b5a in make_child (s=0x7f7816824938, slot=4)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:758
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#13 0x00007f78160757e4 in perform_idle_server_maintenance (
    _pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>,
    s=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:893
#14 ap_mpm_run (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>,
    s=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:1097
#15 0x00007f781604a350 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fff69cdda08)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/main.c:742
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this is already reported PHP [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60383). There are some workarounds, try to apply one of them.